# What are the symbols for specializations and generalizations etc. in crow foot notation

Tags: erd

My university is forcing me to learn from a terrible textbook on ERD's, in which they are using a notation I personally don't like because I've never seen it used before (the book is so bad it doesn't even say what notation they're using), and I like learning it using a more common notation. Therefore I chose to learn it using the crow foot notation. (Please enlighten me if you think this is a bad decision)

Now the textbook is covering is-a(n) relationships (a.k.a. specializations/generalizations) and I'd like to know how I have to represent one in a consistent way with martin/crow foot notation... I learned about it thanks to a yt video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTG1zl8PkXk) but I noticed he's not using the same notation I'm using.

So how do I represent a specialization or generalization in crow foot notation? Or is crow foot notation only specific to cardinality? In my textbook, a few pages ahead, I also see concepts like multidimensional relationships (entity A has the same relation with entity B as with entity C) and relationships that refer to the same entity itsself (so 1 employee can hire multiple other employee's). Extra much love if you can show me how I should draw those as well :)

Unfortunately I could not find much information on this using search engines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching on "EER Diagram PDF".  You'll get more images than you can shake a stick at.  Some of them use crow's foot notation.  Others don't.

The extra "E" stands for "Enhanced".  This has to do with the fact that the original ER model did not have modeling conventions for Gen-spec  (superclass/subclass) or for unions.

Unlike most people, I prefer to make a sharp distinction between diagrams that depict an ER model and ones that depict a relational model.  Contrary to prevailing opinion,  ER modeling isn't just "relational lite".  It's a different model, with different purposes.  You can look up the history if you are really interested.

I tend to use crow's foot notation in ER diagrams,  and I always leave out junction boxes and foreign keys.  This makes the diagram more useful for stakeholders who want to see the big picture.

I like arrowhead notation for relational diagrams.  Foreign keys and junction boxes must be included in relational diagrams.  They are part of the model, and implement relationships.

As far as a relational table design for gen-spec,  I don't think you can beat Fowler's treatment of the subject.  Try searching on "Fowler Class Table Inheritance" for an entry point into this aspect of the topic.

Comment: Yeah, I also came across that wikipedia article :P Sadly wikipedia is lacking quite some information on this topic. What is a junction box? Is it a derived table? You're a life saver by the way.

Comment: So ER models are more useful for explaining since it models real life better. But in the end you always have to convert it back to a relational model so you can implement it, right? Are there any more advantages or uses for ER models?

Comment: If this is an acceptable answer, you might consider accepting it.

Comment: I really like the way you explain the difference between ER's and relational databases, but I'm still a bit lost at how to represent specializations etc. graphically. I'm going to check out the links you provided.

Comment: A junction box is a (picture of) a table that implements a many-to-many relationship.  It has two (or more) foreign keys, which taken together uniquely identify a given row in the table.  For example, if there are three tables, namely Course, Course_Student, and Student, the middle table is a junction box.  There are alternate terms.

Comment: Well, relational is the biggest game in town, but it isn't the only game in town.  By the time you get out of school and start climbing the ladder, you may find that "post-relational" databases have gained ground.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ment by a derived table. English is not my primary language :) Can you tell me what notation is used on page 8 on the link you provided before editing your answer? (http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/4710/f11/Ch08.pdf)

Comment: Sorry.  That notation is novel to me.  Incidentally, I thought my first effort at a response was a mess.  That's why I rewrote it.

Comment: Do you have any ER examples you've worked on using crow foot notation? That would mean the world to me. I'm stuck right now as I don't know how to design ER's using the right notation. Also, is arrowhead a common notation (perhaps it has a synonym like "Bachman")? I can't find any information about it using google.